# DOS batch - rename all files in subdirectories to have subdirectory name prefix

Tags: batch-file, dos, rename, subdirectory

I basically have a setup like this:

```
C:\Upload\A
C:\Upload\B
C:\Upload\C
C:\Upload\D
C:\Upload\E
```

Where `A`, `B`, `C`, `D`, `E` are always different (product IDs) and will always be a different amount (it won't always be 5 sub-directories). Each of these sub-directories contains 24 images numbered numerically 01-24.

I need to create a batch file that looks at the Upload directory, gets the name of each sub-directory and appends that name to beginning of each image file contained within that sub-directory.

So, `C:\Upload\A\01.jpg` would become `C:\Upload\A\A-O1.jpg` as well as the other 23 images in each sub-directory.

The batch file needs to do the same for every sub-directory within the Upload directory.

This sounds extremely complicated to me and where I have started to try and write this, I don't yet have anything worth sharing in this post.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Are you really using DOS? (I doubt it) or some version of Windows?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will rename files in the subdirectories of "C:\Upload"

```
@echo off
for /d %%D in (C:\Upload\*) do (
  for /f "eol=: delims=" %%F in ('dir /b /a-d "%%D" ^| findstr /vbic:"%%~nD-"') do (
    ren "%%D\%%F" "%%~nD-%%F"
  )
)
```

I put in extra code to prevent renaming the same file twice. You should be able to safely run the script multiple times.

If you want to recurseively rename files in each subdirectory tree, then a slight change is needed to the code.

```
@echo off
for /d /r "C:\Utils" %%D in (*) do (
  for /f "eol=: delims=" %%F in ('dir /b /a-d "%%D" ^| findstr /vbic:"%%~nD-"') do (
    ren "%%D\%%F" "%%~nD-%%F"
  )
)
```

Comment: Thanks...that works exactly like I need it to!  Would it be possible to do this exact same thing with PHP?

Comment: @WillIrvine - Sorry, I don't know anything about PHP. Don't forget to accept the answer if your original question is answered to your satisfaction.